# WinForms listbox containing custom controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, custom-controls

Is it possible to make a listbox that lists a bunch of custom controls? I would assume that you might have to invoke some sort of custom drawing of the child objects, but I do not know how to do that. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Are you using Winforms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: To do this sort of thing I add a *FlowLayoutPanel* then add my controls to it in some fancy fashion.

Comment: Is there a way to force the scrollbar on a FlowLayoutPanel to appear?

Comment: yes, dont remember exactly but I think is the autoscroll prop., you may want to double buffer your form so no flicker occurs when scrolling =]

Comment: @MarkP: 
1. I think that the biggest thing that missing from the _FlowLayoutPanel_ solution, is the ability to know which "object" within the list is selected, and you need to implement it yourself.


2.To show the scrollbar, just set the property _AutoScroll_ to true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A ListBox is not designed to be a container control.  Its scrollbar cannot scroll the controls.  It is in general something you want to avoid, putting a lot of controls in, say, a Panel whose AutoScroll property is True will make your UI unresponsive.  Controls are expensive objects.

Take a look at the ListBox.DrawItem event.  You can draw your own item and make it look just the way you want it with the Graphics class methods.  And it is very cheap.  There's a very good example in the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem%28VS.90%29.aspx) for the event.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before not by using a FlowLayoutPanel, but just a normal Panel with controls Docked to the top. You can add a scroll bar, etc.

This works quite nicely for a few controls. More than a few, and it begins to really slow down. If you have the time, I would look into drawing a fake control in it's place, like in [Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248468/listbox-containing-custom-controls/3248974#3248974), then when the user clicks one of the items, replace it with a real control that looks exactly the same. When that item loses focus, dispose it and change the underlying list.

Comment: @Luiscencio - It was more of an answer in response to your comment, actually. Notice I said I *didn't* use a FlowLayoutPanel, but a simple Panel. The reason for this is if you want to simulate a list box, they're all arranged vertically, and not in the "flow" layout from the FlowLayoutPanel. (Besides, if you wanted your comment to be an answer, you should have posted it as an answer.)

Comment: @Luiscencio - I'm going to stop trying to detect sarcasm and simply reply with a "Thank you" =]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:
[Flexible List Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333864/Flexible-List-Control)

I wrote that article some time back.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy with WPF, just use the basic composition.  In a WinForms world, you'll probably need to make the container a custom control.

Comment: I never actually used WPF, so I'll stick with WinForms. So the container and the items would have to be a custom control.

Comment: The container would be, the items might not have to be.  Presumably your custom container would contain a collection of `Control` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
        rect.Offset(0, -rect.Top);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
        {
            Control control = (Control)listBox.Items[e.Index];
            control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, rect);
            rect = e.Bounds;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
```